# Send a DM and then reacts to the message once a new user joins

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so every time a new user joins I sent the users a message using

```
client.on ("guildMemberAdd", member => {

member.send("WELCOME")})
```

Now, is there any way for the bot to react to that message?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Syntle's answer, but uses promises instead. (My preferred use)

```
   member.send("WELCOME").then(function(msg){
       msg.react("");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to contain `member.send()` in a variable and then use the [`.react()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react) method on it.

So your solution is:

```js
const msg = await member.send("WELCOME")
await msg.react("");
```